# HP G60-552NR Memory

Tags: laptop, memory, memory-limit

This is a two part question.

1. how much memory can I install in this computer, not how much is recommended. Can you go beyond 8G
2. How much faster is the PC 6400 to PC 5300 chip?

Answer (score 2):

8GB is the max according to [HP's website.](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01893226&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&cc=us&dlc=en&lc=en&product=4051826)

You probably will not notice a huge difference in the real world. Here is a comparison from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR2_SDRAM):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [Windows Experience Index](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_System_Assessment_Tool) for my RAM dropped from 5.9 to 5.3 (If I remember correctly) when I installed a slower PC 5200 module. That's a difference of 10%. It can depend on the chipset, because AMD has a better memory controller. But the price difference is only 1€ for a module, hence it's better to buy the faster memory if you want to be sure, as well as minimize cost versus speed.

Comment: By *performance index*, do you mean [Windows Experience Index](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-experience-index)?

Comment: @iglvzx: Yes, it goes up to 7,9 for each component.

Comment: WEI's are not linear. 5.9 to 5.3 is not "10%" in any meaningful sense.

Comment: WEI isn't exactly your best benchmark either. For example, I use a Z68 board with IntelSRT (SSD Caching of HDDs). In real life, the setup works very fast, but in Benchmarking, it's much slower since it hasn't cached any data.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: What do you mean 10% isn't meaningful sense?

Comment: @David It's like when guys rate a girl from 1 to 10. A 10 isn't "11% better than a 9" in any meaningful sense because the scale isn't linear.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: A 10 to a 9 is only a 10% difference and not 11% difference. What do you mean with 11%? Minus 11%?

Comment: 9 to 10 is 11%. 10 to 9 is 10%. But it doesn't matter, if the scale isn't linear, a 10% difference in the number isn't a meaningful difference of 10%. A girl who rates a 10 is not 10% or 11% better than a girl who rates a 9 because the scale isn't linear. You can't translate a 10% difference in the measurement to a 10% difference in the thing measured unless the scale is linear. (40 degrees is not "twice as hot" as 20 degrees, nor is 10 degrees "half as hot" as 20. That's nonsense.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: 40% is just 50% better then 20%.

Comment: Actually, it depends on the scale. There is a sense in which 40% is 20% better than 20%. With a non-linear scale, there is no meaningful sense.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Maybe it's a language thing. To bad that you even don't understand my math.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: When you say a girl with a 10 isn't 10% or 11% better then a girl with a 9 then do you count the votes?

Comment: @David Because the scale is non-linear, you can't do anything with numbers. One is a 10, the other is a 9. That's it. Similarly, one WEI is 5.3, the other is 5.9. Since the scale is not linear, you can't just plug them into a formula to get a percentage difference.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: But it's normal to use percentage to show the difference or the change. When I calculate the tax it's the same. What do you propose then to make the change understandable?

Comment: @David I'd suggest either a measurement from a benchmark that provides results on a linear scale or a common sense description like "big difference", "no significant difference", "slight difference", or something like that. Almost anything is better than a result that appears to be mathematically precise but is completely meaningless.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Good point. Thanks for the info.